# How to explicitly find a natural number N that satisfies the statement in the definition of the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For example, in this question:

$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+2x}\right)=1$

For every epsilon > 0, I am asked to find explicitly a natural number N which
satisfies the statement in the definition of the limit.

What does find explicitly $N$ means? Do I just prove it as usual?

$|\frac{x^2}{x^2+2x} -1|< Ɛ$

Continue with this I got:

$n+2 > \frac{2}{Ɛ}$

and then I take:

$ N = 2[\frac{1}{Ɛ}] + 1$

then since $n >= N$:

$n+2 >= 2[\frac{1}{Ɛ}] + 1 + 2$

therefore, $N = 2[\frac{1}{Ɛ}] + 3$, did I just found my $N$ or is it asking for something numerical? I am confused?

Comment: Indicating an $N$ as a function of $\varepsilon$ - say, in terms of floor function, elementary functions and the usual high-school algebraic machinery - should be enough. I did not go through your calculations but, yes, an explanation such as yours should be fine.

Comment: Your analysis that $(N+2) > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$ is good.  Furthermore, once $N$ is so defined by the above, you know that for any $n > N, (n+2) > (N+2) > \frac{2}{\epsilon}.$  Therefore, by my last sentence, the specification of $(N+2) > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$, in an of itself is **game over** - you are done.  Your math teacher would probably want you to explicitly show how you reached the constraint on $N$ and for you to also indicate that $n>N \implies (n+2)>(N+2).$

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for the useful feedback. I thought $n >= N$ is just the definition of the limit for the sequence, if not then I am unsure what you are referring to. Many thanks again!

Comment: The idea is that you have to find a constraint on $\epsilon$ that is represented by a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $n$ satisfies the constraint.  The constraint that you found was that for any positive integer $n$, $(n+2) > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$.  What your analysis indicates is that if $N$ is specified such that $(N+2) > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$, then any positive integer $n>N$ will also satisfy that constraint.  ...see next comment

Comment: The basic idea that a sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ converges to a limit $L$ is that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n > N, ~|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Your analysis shows that for a given $\epsilon > 0$ if $N$ is specified by $(N+2) > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$ and $n$ is any positive integer $> N$, then $\left|\frac{n^2}{n^2 - 2n} - 1\right| < \epsilon$.

Comment: @user2661923 I think I know what you mean? So can I then say: $2[\frac{1}{Ɛ}] + 3 > \frac{2}{Ɛ}$ therefore $n + 2 > \frac{2}{Ɛ}$ or $Ɛ > \frac{2}{n+2}$ and thats it? since I have proven $|a_n-a|< Ɛ$

Comment: @user2661923 Huge Thanks. Yep sorry I am asking too many questions in the comment.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per back and forth with OP, this answer is intended to eliminate any confusion around the problem.  The answer will (mostly) use analysis already done by the OP.

---

> For example, in this question:

> $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+2x}\right)=1$

> For every epsilon > 0, I am asked to find explicitly a natural number N which
> satisfies the statement in the definition of the limit.

For all positive integers $n$, let $a_n$ be defined as
$\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2+2n}\right).$

There are two ways that the problem might be interpreted.  The narrow way is that given $\epsilon > 0$, you are being asked to find $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $|a_N - 1| < \epsilon.$

The alternative intrepretation, which I will adopt, and which might not have been intended is that you are to find $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that for every element $a_n$ in the subsequence
$\{a_{N}, a_{(N+1)}, a_{(N+2)}, \cdots \}$ you have that 
$|a_n - 1| < \epsilon.$

The reason that I have chosen the 2nd interpretation, which is moderately more onerous, is that this interpretation represents the standard definition of a sequence converging to a limit.

That is, normally, you show that a sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ converges to a limit $L$ by showing that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a positive integer $N$, such that for all positive integers $n \geq N$ (or $n > N$), $|a_n - L| < \epsilon.$

Hijacking the analysis already done by the OP: 
it is clear that each element $a_n$ will be between $0$ and $1$. 
Therefore, the first objective is to find an $N$ such that

$$1 - a_N < \epsilon \implies \tag{Constraint-1}$$

$1 - \frac{N^2}{N^2 + 2N} < \epsilon \implies$

$\frac{N^2 + 2N - N^2}{N^2 + 2N} < \epsilon \implies$

$\frac{2N}{N^2 + 2N} < \epsilon \implies$

$\frac{2}{N+2} < \epsilon \implies$

$\frac{N+2}{2} > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies$

$$(N+2) > \frac{2}{\epsilon}.\tag{Constraint-2}$$

What you actually have is that if Constraint-1 is satisfied for a specific positive integer $N$, then Constraint-2 is also satisfied.  **However**, what you **want** is the reverse.

Notice which way the $\implies$ symbols are directed.  However, if you examine the **actual** analysis step-by-step, you will see that each step has a (hidden) **bidirectional** implication.  That is a given step is true $\iff$ the next step is true.

This means that if Constraint-2 is satisfied for a specific positive integer $N$, then Constraint-1 will also be satisfied.

It further means that if $n$ is **any** positive integer that satisfies Constraint-2, then $n$ will also satisfy Constraint-1.

Therefore, for a given fixed $\epsilon > 0$, specify $N$ by Constraint-2.  This implies that $a_N$ satisfies Constraint-1.

But there is more.
Suppose that $n$ is any positive integer such that $n > N$.
Then, $(n+2) > (N+2).$ 
Therefore, $n$ **also** satisfies Constraint-2. 
Therefore, $a_n$ **also** satisfies Constraint-1.

Thus, Constraint-2 provides the specification for $N$, based on $\epsilon$ such that each element in 
$\{a_N, a_{(N+1)}, a_{(N+2)}, \cdots \}$ satisfies Constraint-1.